# MySQL query returning a syntax error

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Im running a query like so but getting an error

```
insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id) values (select product_id from oc_product where model='Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and price=36.26 limit 1, select category_id from oc_category_description where name='Bakery & Bread');
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `values` with an `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into oc_product_to_category (product_id, category_id)
    select (select product_id
            from oc_product
            where model = 'Schar Gluten & Wheat Free Classic White Bread, 14.1 oz (Pack ' and
                  price = 36.26
            limit 1
           ),
           (select category_id
            from oc_category_description
            where name='Bakery & Bread'
           );
```

Your problem, though, is probably that the second subquery is not surrounded by parentheses.